# How to make a chart display only a certain number of labels out of total labels in chartjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs

So I have a chart that has over 400 values on the x-axis, taken throughout the day at a certain equal interval. I want to show only 24 labels at the bottom, representing the 24 hrs of the day and the rest be shown the points on the chart itself but not on the x-axis. It's a line chart with currently having labels as an array of 400+ values and spread at multiples of 8 starting from 0000.

Comment: Can you please add the code?

Comment: You have to use `xAxes[{ ticks: { callback: function(value, index, values) { ... } } }]` and `return null` when you don't want ticks.